# How to groupby the keys in dictionary and sum up the values in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas-groupby

How to `groupby` two `keys` in `dictionary` and get the sum of the values of the other key `val`.

`Input:`

```
data = {'key1':['a','a', 'b', 'b'], 'key2':['m','n', 'm', 'm'], 
        'val':[1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

In this example, I want to `groupby` the `key1` and the `key2`, and then sum up the value in `val`.

`Expected:`

```
data = {'key1':['a','a', 'b', 'b'], 'key2':['m','n', 'm', 'm'], 
        'val':[1, 2, 3, 4], 'val_sum':[1, 2, 7, 7]}
```

Actually, I don't want to convert the dictionary `data` into `pandas.DataFrame` then convert back to `dictionary` to achieve it, because my `data` is actually very big.

---

**Update:**

To help understand the generating `val_sum`, I post my code using `pandas.DataFrame`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
tmp = df.groupby(['key1', 'key2'])['val'].agg({'val_sum':'sum'})
df['val_sum'] = df.set_index(['key1', 'key2']).index.map(tmp.to_dict()['val_sum'])
```

And the result is shown as follows:

```
  key1 key2  val  val_sum
0    a    m    1        1
1    a    n    2        2
2    b    m    3        7
3    b    m    4        7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your own summing solution using a defaultdict, say as follows.

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = {'key1':['a','a', 'b', 'b'], 'key2':['m','n', 'm', 'm'], 
        'val':[1, 2, 3, 4]}


keys_to_group = ['key1','key2']

temp = defaultdict(int) #initializes sum to zero


for i, *key_group in zip(data['val'], *[data[key] for key in keys_to_group]):
    print(i, key_group) #key_group now looks like ['a', 'm'] or ['b', 'm'] or so on
    temp[tuple(key_group)] += i

val_sum = [temp[key_group] for key_group in zip(*[data[key] for key in keys_to_group])]

data['val_sum'] = val_sum

print(data)
{'key1': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'],
 'key2': ['m', 'n', 'm', 'm'],
 'val': [1, 2, 3, 4],
 'val_sum': [1, 2, 7, 7]}
```

Having said that however, it does seem like your data is more suited for tabular structures, and if you plan to do more than just this one operation, it might make sense to load it up in a dataframe anyways.